# "Mein teuerstes Auto " ist richtig?

Tags: grammatical-case

Kann man die deklinierte Form von Superlativ mit Possessivartikel benutzen? Z.b ist der Satz " Mein teuerstes Auto" richtig? Ich habe in Deutsch-Grammatik gesehen, dass deklinierte Form von Superlativ nur mit bestimmten Artikel möglich ist. Das ist falsch ?

Answer (score 7):

## **Allgemein**

Der Superlativ von etwas ist einzigartig. Es gibt viele hohe Türme, aber nur einen höchsten Turm. Damit ist dieser Turm (oder allgemein das Objekt) immer bekannt, und es macht nur Sinn, den bestimmten Artikel zu verwenden.

Aber:

Das Possessivpronomen übernimmt hier die Rolle eines bestimmten Artikels. Vergleiche die Sätze

> Mein Auto ist rot. (=Ich habe nur ein Auto, und **das** Auto ist rot)
> Eins meiner Autos ist rot. (=Ich habe mehrere Autos und eins von ihnen ist rot)
> Mein schnellstes Auto ist rot. (=Ich habe mehrere<sup>1</sup> Autos und **das** schnellste von ihnen ist rot)

## **Die höchsten Türme**

Gruppiere ich mehrere Objekte zu einem Superlativ zusammen, so ist es möglich den unbestimmten Artikel in Kombination mit dem bestimmten Artikel zu verwenden:

> Ich war schon auf einem **der höchsten** Türme der Welt. (Der zum Superlativ gehörige bestimmte Artikel steht hier im **Genitiv**)

## **Unbekannte und/oder nicht vorhandene Superlative**

Es kann der unbestimmte Artikel verwendet werden, wenn es nicht klar ist, ob es einen Superlativ des Objekts gibt:

> Gibt es eine größte Zahl?
> Nein, es gibt keine größte Zahl / Nein, eine größte Zahl gibt es nicht.

<sup>1</sup>Ich sehe schon den Kommentar der sagt, wenn man nur 1 Auto hat, ist es automatisch das schnellste. Technisch korrekt, aber unüblich zu sagen.

Comment: "Es gibt viele hohe Türme, aber nur einen höchsten Turm." - natürlich kann es auch mehrere höchste Türme geben, wenn sie alle dieselbe Höhe haben. Dass die Formulierung "ein höchster Turm" dennoch unüblich ist, ist davon unbenommen.

Comment: Ich hab mir den Kommentar extra verkniffen, damit die Erklärung hier einfach bleibt, bzw das Beispiel im 2. Absatz weiter ausgeführt. Aber natürlich hast du Recht.